# update status text without page reload

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have a web app! I set a status text for users that is shown below the profile picture of the user. Whenever the user updates the status text, the page reloads on button click, and  then the new status appears below the picture. Is there a way to prevent this page reloading and still make the status text changed?

On submit, the new status text is inserted/updated into the database table and then on page load, it is fetched.

Comment: You can use Client event to set the text. Or use put the StatusText in UpdatePanel

Comment: What if something happens whilst inserting? Would you still want the status changed?

Comment: Something like? An error?

Comment: What else would I need to do apart from putting my StatusText in updatePanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ajax,

- Place your **Update Button** and **Status TextBox** inside a `AjaxUpdatePanel`
- If it's not possible to add both (**Update Button** and **Status TextBox**) to a single `AjaxUpdatePanel` (as your HTML design), add two different Ajax UpdatePanels (to **Update Button** and **Status TextBox**) and call `yourstatusupdatepanelname.Update();` from **Update Button** `Click event`

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery ajax to do that and it is easy and will not load your page every time you click a the button:

[Asp.net Jquery ajax example](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 0):

you just asign the status again in button click on success execution of sql statement

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find out using about ajax , postback for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **Timer_Tick** Event